# Webpack can't find lodash submodules on linux but works fine on macOS

Tags: node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, electron, babeljs

I have realized that my electron application does not want to build properly on linux, whereas on macOS it works fine. I'm not quite sure why.

So on macOS this works fine

```
let _snakecase = require('lodash/snakecase')
let _cloneDeep = require('lodash/clonedeep')
let _filter = require('lodash/filter')
```

On linux this throws errors that it can't find the dependencies `lodash/snakecase` and `lodash/clonedeep`. Strangely enough it **can** find `lodash/filter`. I can only get it to work if import it like so:

```
import {snakecase as _snakecase} from 'lodash'
import {clonedeep as _cloneDeep} from 'lodash'
import {filter as _filter} from 'lodash'
```

But my question is why can I `require('lodash/filter')` but not `require('lodash/snakecase')`? I don't even know where to start looking to debug this.

The exact error when I try to require `lodash/snakecase`:

```
This dependency was not found:

* lodash/snakecase in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0&bustCache!./src/views/modals/ChannelModal.vue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file system on macOS is case-*in*sensitive by default, which means when you ask for a file that doesn't exist, let's say `file.js`, it will gladly give you `FILE.js` if that one exists. On a case-sensitive file system, it would just tell you that `file.js` doesn't exist and result in an error. The file systems on Linux are case-sensitive.

The files you are looking for are [`cloneDeep.js`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/e8c87cfc45ceb1a5b6ba578bf7c78b669042275b/cloneDeep.js) and [`snakeCase.js`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/e8c87cfc45ceb1a5b6ba578bf7c78b669042275b/snakeCase.js), but you're trying to import `clonedeep` and `snakecase` respectively, which do not exist. `lodash/filter` works because [`filter.js`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/e8c87cfc45ceb1a5b6ba578bf7c78b669042275b/filter.js) actually exists.

The correct imports would be:

```
let _snakecase = require('lodash/snakeCase')
let _cloneDeep = require('lodash/cloneDeep')
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't think of that. They should really fix that in the documentation on the respective npmjs page.